# Cordova PushPlugin onNotificationAPN(e) callback not working or defined

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working with Cordova / PhoneGap plugin PushPlugin and I have it setup pretty well and working, including a test .php and .pem file on my local server using a live device (iPhone 5).  IOS 8.  There are a couple of issues, with the main one being the call to this function in index.html:

```
            function onNotificationAPN(event) {
    console.log(event);
        if (event.alert) {
             $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + event.alert + '</li>');
             // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
             navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
        }

        if (event.sound) {
            // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
            var snd = new Media(event.sound);
            snd.play();
        }

        if (event.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, event.badge);
        }
    }
```

The console output for event is:

{"event":"message","payload":{"aps":{"alert":"My first push notification!","sound":"default"}},"foreground":true}

When the App is in the foreground the function onNotificationAPN(event) doesn't fire.  "event" appears to be returned in or is converted to JSON format.

The IOS registration line is:

```
pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});
```

How can I modify the code to decode the JSON format  and display the alert, play sound, set the badge when the application is in the foreground.  There must also be some documentation about the formats that the callback can take and the various options.  Otherwise, seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little playing around I guess that the callback "event" is actually already a JSON object:

```
        console.log(e.event);
        console.log(e.payload.aps.alert);
        console.log(e.payload.aps.sound);
        console.log(e.foreground);
```

prints out message, My first push notification!, default and true in the log.